# Having trouble importing Theano, circular dependencies

Tags: python, python-theano

I'm trying to use an external library called `Theano`.  When I run
`import theano`

I get an error message saying "AttributeError:

```
 partially initialized module 'theano' has no attribute 'compile' (most likely due to a circular import).
```

Is there any way around this?

I'm in Google Colab.  I ran `!pip install theano` before trying to import it, no problems there.

Comment: It sounds like you may have a circular import. There are many online resources that can help you address the problem since we can't see your code here.

Comment: e.g. https://stackabuse.com/python-circular-imports/

Comment: The problem is that it's not my code, it's an external library.  I'll make that more clear

Comment: From the project's [github page](https://github.com/Theano/Theano): Theano ... is being continued as PyTensor: https://www.github.com/pymc-devs/pytensor

Comment: @Marat Thank you, I didn't see that!  I'll look into PyTensor then